# Как выровнять текст в Label по верху?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Код:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
from tkinter import *


root=Tk()

root.title('Калькулятор')
root.resizable(False, False)

'''
Функции которые пишут:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,+,-,*,/ и решают прымиер
'''
def b1():#Пишет 1
    e.insert(END, '1')
def b2():#Пишет 2
    e.insert(END, '2')
def b3():#Пишет 3
    e.insert(END, '3')
def b4():#Пишет 4
    e.insert(END, '4')
def b5():#Пишет 5
    e.insert(END, '5')
def b6():#Пишет 6
    e.insert(END, '6')
def b7():#Пишет 7
    e.insert(END, '7')
def b8():#Пишет 8
    e.insert(END, '8')
def b9():#Пишет 9
    e.insert(END, '9')
def b0():#Пишет 0
    e.insert(END, '0')
def b_plus():#Пишет +
    e.insert(END, '+')
def b_minus():#Пишет -
    e.insert(END, '-')
def b_multiply():#Пишет *
    e.insert(END, '*')
def b_division():#Пишет /
    e.insert(END, '/')
def b_clean():#Всё стирает
    e.delete(0, END)
def b_is():#Решает прымер
    try:
        a = e.get()
        otvet = eval(a)
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, otvet )
    except:
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' )
        
'''Функции для ковертера температур'''
def f_in_c():
    try:
        a = e.get()
        a = eval(a)
        a=int(a)
        c = (a-32)/1.8
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, c)
    except:
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' ) 
def c_in_f():
    try:    
        a = e.get()
        a = eval(a)
        a = int(a)
        c = (a*1.8)+32
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, c)    
    except:
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' ) 


"""Функции для конвертера масс"""

def kar_in_g():
    try:    
        a = e.get()
        a = eval(a)
        a = int(a)
        c = a*0.2
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, c)
    except:
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' ) 
def g_in_kar():
    try:
        a = e.get()
        a = eval(a)
        a = int(a)
        c = a*5
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, c)
    except:
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' )
def N_in_g():
    try:
        a = e.get()
        a = eval(a)
        a = int(a)
        c = a*101.971601
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, c)
    except:
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, c)
def g_in_N():
    try:
        a = e.get()
        a = eval(a)
        a = int(a)
        c = a*0.009807
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, c)
    except:
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, c)
def lb_in_g():
    try:
        a = e.get()
        a = eval(a)
        a = int(a)
        c = a*453.59237
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, c)    
    except:
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' ) 
def g_in_lb():
    try:
        a = e.get()
        a = eval(a)
        a = int(a)
        c = a*0.00220462262
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, c)    
    except:
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' )




pixel = PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)

e = Entry()#Строка для вывода данных


'''Все кнопки с цифрами и +,-,*,/,=,C'''
b1 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=35, height=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='1', command=b1, relief = FLAT)
b2 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=35, height=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='2', command=b2, relief = FLAT)
b3 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=35, height=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='3', command=b3, relief = FLAT)
b4 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=35, height=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='4', command=b4, relief = FLAT)
b5 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=35, height=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='5', command=b5, relief = FLAT)
b6 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=35, height=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='6', command=b6, relief = FLAT)
b7 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=35, height=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='7', command=b7, relief = FLAT)
b8 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=35, height=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='8', command=b8, relief = FLAT)
b9 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=35, height=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='9', command=b9, relief = FLAT)
b0 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=35, height=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='0', command=b0, relief = FLAT)
b_plus = Button(bg ='orange', height=35, width=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='+', relief = FLAT, command = b_plus)
b_minus = Button(bg ='orange', height=35, width=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='-', relief = FLAT, command = b_minus)
b_clean = Button(bg ='yellow', height=35, width=98, compound="c", image=pixel, text='C', relief = FLAT, command = b_clean)
b_multiply = Button(bg = 'orange', height=85, width=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='*', relief = FLAT, command = b_multiply)
b_division = Button(bg ='orange', height=85, width=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text=':', relief = FLAT, command = b_division)
b_is = Button(bg = 'lightblue', width=98, height=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='=', relief = FLAT, command = b_is)

'''Кнопки конвертера тамператур'''
l_t = Label(text='Температура', anchor=S)
c_in_f = Button( text='C→F', command=c_in_f, compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=22)
f_in_c = Button( text='F→C', command=f_in_c, compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=22)


'''Кнопки конвертера масс'''
l_m = Label(text='Масса', anchor='n')
kar_in_g = Button( text='кар→г', compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=24, command=kar_in_g)
g_in_kar = Button( text='г→кар', compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=24, command=g_in_kar)
N_in_g = Button(text='Н→г', compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=28, command = N_in_g)
g_in_N = Button(text='г→Н', compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=28, command = g_in_N)
lb_in_g = Button(text='фунти→г', compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=28, command = lb_in_g)
g_in_lb = Button(text='г→фунти', compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=28, command = g_in_lb)

'''С помощью функции grid() упаковуем все виджети '''

'''Температура'''
l_t.grid(row=1, column=4, columnspan=4, pady=10)
c_in_f.grid(row=1, column=4, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, ipady=0)
f_in_c.grid(row=1, column=6, columnspan=2, rowspan=2,ipady=0)

'''Масса'''
l_m.grid(row=2, column=4,rowspan=2, columnspan=4)
kar_in_g.grid(row=3, column=4, columnspan=2)
g_in_kar.grid(row=3, column=6, columnspan=2)
N_in_g.grid(row=4, column=4, columnspan=2)
g_in_N.grid(row=4, column=6, columnspan=2)
lb_in_g.grid(row=5, column=4, columnspan=2)
g_in_lb.grid(row=5, column=6, columnspan=2)

b_clean.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2)
b_plus.grid(row=1, column=0)
b_minus.grid(row=1, column=1)
b_division.grid(row=2, column=3, rowspan=2)
b_multiply.grid(row=4, column=3, rowspan=2)
b_is.grid(row=5, column=1,columnspan=2)
b1.grid(row=2, column=0)
b2.grid(row=2, column=1)
b3.grid(row=2, column=2)
b4.grid(row=3, column=0)
b5.grid(row=3, column=1)
b6.grid(row=3, column=2)
b7.grid(row=4, column=0)
b8.grid(row=4, column=1)
b9.grid(row=4, column=2)
b0.grid(row=5, column=0)
e.grid(ipady=10, ipadx=45, row=0, column=0, columnspan=12)

root.mainloop()
```

Нужно текст в метке  `l_m` немного поднять

Comment: Уже пробовал, не помогает

Comment: І все таки я не зрозумів!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как мне вставить Label над кнопками?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1145508/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-label-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Answer (score 0):

Лучше панель с кнопками перевода между единицами измерения разместить в отдельном фрейме, а внутри этого фрейма уже по сетке все располагать (вместо того чтобы пытаться красиво разместить несколько элементов управления в одной ячейке общей сетки):

```
converter_frame = Frame()
converter_frame.grid(row=1, column=4, rowspan=4)

'''Кнопки конвертера тамператур'''
l_t = Label(converter_frame, text='Температура', anchor=S)
c_in_f = Button(converter_frame, text='C→F', command=c_in_f, compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=22)
f_in_c = Button(converter_frame, text='F→C', command=f_in_c, compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=22)


'''Кнопки конвертера масс'''
l_m = Label(converter_frame, text='Масса')
kar_in_g = Button(converter_frame, text='кар→г', compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=24, command=kar_in_g)
g_in_kar = Button(converter_frame, text='г→кар', compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=24, command=g_in_kar)
N_in_g = Button(converter_frame, text='Н→г', compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=28, command = N_in_g)
g_in_N = Button(converter_frame, text='г→Н', compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=28, command = g_in_N)
lb_in_g = Button(converter_frame, text='фунти→г', compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=28, command = lb_in_g)
g_in_lb = Button(converter_frame, text='г→фунти', compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=28, command = g_in_lb)

'''С помощью функции grid() упаковуем все виджети '''

'''Температура'''
l_t.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=N)
c_in_f.grid(row=2, column=1)
f_in_c.grid(row=2, column=2)

'''Масса'''
l_m.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2)
kar_in_g.grid(row=4, column=1)
g_in_kar.grid(row=4, column=2)
N_in_g.grid(row=5, column=1)
g_in_N.grid(row=5, column=2)
lb_in_g.grid(row=6, column=1)
g_in_lb.grid(row=6, column=2)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]