# Как мне вставить Label над кнопками?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

код:

```
from tkinter import *


root=Tk()

root.title('Калькулятор')
root.resizable(False, False)
root['bg']='white'
'''
Функции которые пишут:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,+,-,*,/ и решают прымиер
'''
def b1():#Пишет 1
   e.insert(END, '1')
def b2():#Пишет 2
   e.insert(END, '2')
def b3():#Пишет 3
   e.insert(END, '3')
def b4():#Пишет 4
   e.insert(END, '4')
def b5():#Пишет 5
   e.insert(END, '5')
def b6():#Пишет 6
   e.insert(END, '6')
def b7():#Пишет 7
   e.insert(END, '7')
def b8():#Пишет 8
   e.insert(END, '8')
def b9():#Пишет 9
   e.insert(END, '9')
def b0():#Пишет 0
   e.insert(END, '0')
def b_plus():#Пишет +
   e.insert(END, '+')
def b_minus():#Пишет -
   e.insert(END, '-')
def b_multiply():#Пишет *
   e.insert(END, '*')
def b_division():#Пишет /
   e.insert(END, '/')
def b_float():#Пишет .
   e.insert(END, '.')
def b_clean():#Всё стирает
   e.delete(0, END)
def b_clean1():
   e.delete(len(e.get())-1)
def b_is():#Решает прымер
   try:
       a = e.get()
       otvet = eval(a)
       e.delete(0, END)
       e.insert(END, otvet )
   except:
       e.delete(0, END)
       e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' )
       
'''Функции для ковертера температур'''
def f_in_c():
   try:
       a = e.get()
       a = eval(a)
       a=int(a)
       c = (a-32)/1.8
       e.delete(0, END)
       e.insert(END, c)
   except:
       e.delete(0, END)
       e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' ) 
def c_in_f():
   try:    
       a = e.get()
       a = eval(a)
       a = int(a)
       c = (a*1.8)+32
       e.delete(0, END)
       e.insert(END, c)    
   except:
       e.delete(0, END)
       e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' ) 


"""Функции для конвертера масс"""

def kar_in_g():
   try:    
       a = e.get()
       a = eval(a)
       a = int(a)
       c = a*0.2
       e.delete(0, END)
       e.insert(END, c)
   except:
       e.delete(0, END)
       e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' ) 
def g_in_kar():
   try:
       a = e.get()
       a = eval(a)
       a = int(a)
       c = a*5
       e.delete(0, END)
       e.insert(END, c)
   except:
       e.delete(0, END)
       e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' )
def N_in_g():
   try:
       a = e.get()
       a = eval(a)
       a = int(a)
       c = a*101.971601
       e.delete(0, END)
       e.insert(END, c)
   except:
       e.delete(0, END)
       e.insert(END, c)
def g_in_N():
   try:
       a = e.get()
       a = eval(a)
       a = int(a)
       c = a*0.009807
       e.delete(0, END)
       e.insert(END, c)
   except:
       e.delete(0, END)
       e.insert(END, c)
def lb_in_g():
   try:
       a = e.get()
       a = eval(a)
       a = int(a)
       c = a*453.59237
       e.delete(0, END)
       e.insert(END, c)    
   except:
       e.delete(0, END)
       e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' ) 
def g_in_lb():
   try:
       a = e.get()
       a = eval(a)
       a = int(a)
       c = a*0.00220462262
       e.delete(0, END)
       e.insert(END, c)    
   except:
       e.delete(0, END)
       e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' )
def v1():
   try:
       a = e.get()
       a = eval(a)
       a = int(a)
       c = a/3.6
       e.delete(0, END)
       e.insert(END, c)    
   except:
       e.delete(0, END)
       e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' ) 
def v2():
   try:
       a = e.get()
       a = eval(a)
       a = int(a)
       c = a*3.6
       e.delete(0, END)
       e.insert(END, c)    
   except:
       e.delete(0, END)
       e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' )
def x_y():
   e.insert('**')
def x_2():
   try:
       a = e.get()
       a = eval(a)
       a = int(a)
       c = a**(1/2)
       e.delete(0, END)
       e.insert(END, c)    
   except:
       e.delete(0, END)
       e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' )     

pixel = PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)

e = Entry(bd=3)#Строка для вывода данных


'''Все кнопки с цифрами и +,-,*,/,=,C'''
b1 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=34, height=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='1', command=b1, relief = FLAT)
b2 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=34, height=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='2', command=b2, relief = FLAT)
b3 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=34, height=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='3', command=b3, relief = FLAT)
b4 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=34, height=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='4', command=b4, relief = FLAT)
b5 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=34, height=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='5', command=b5, relief = FLAT)
b6 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=34, height=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='6', command=b6, relief = FLAT)
b7 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=34, height=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='7', command=b7, relief = FLAT)
b8 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=34, height=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='8', command=b8, relief = FLAT)
b9 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=34, height=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='9', command=b9, relief = FLAT)
b0 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=34, height=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='0', command=b0, relief = FLAT)
b_plus = Button(bg ='orange', height=35, width=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='+', relief = FLAT, command = b_plus)
b_minus = Button(bg ='orange', height=35, width=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='-', relief = FLAT, command = b_minus)
b_clean = Button(bg ='yellow', height=35, width=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='C', relief = FLAT, command = b_clean)
b_clean1 = Button(bg ='yellow', height=35, width=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='→', relief = FLAT, command = b_clean1)
b_multiply = Button(bg = 'orange', height=80, width=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='*', relief = FLAT, command = b_multiply, pady=1)
b_division = Button(bg ='orange', height=80, width=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text=':', relief = FLAT, command = b_division, pady=1)
b_is = Button(bg = 'lightblue', width=34, height=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='=', relief = FLAT, command = b_is)
b_float = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=34, height=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='.', relief = FLAT, command = b_float)

'''Кнопки конвертера тамператур'''
l_t = Label(text='Температура', anchor=N, bg='white', height=2)
c_in_f = Button( text='C→F', command=c_in_f, compound="c", image=pixel, width=35, height=35, relief=FLAT, bg='lightblue')
f_in_c = Button( text='F→C', command=f_in_c, compound="c", image=pixel, width=35, height=35, relief=FLAT, bg='lightblue')


'''Кнопки конвертера масс'''
l_m = Label(text='Масса', anchor=N, height=4, bg='white')
kar_in_g = Button( text='кар→г', compound="c", image=pixel, width=35, height=35, command=kar_in_g, relief=FLAT, bg='green')
g_in_kar = Button( text='г→кар', compound="c", image=pixel, width=35, height=35, command=g_in_kar, relief=FLAT, bg='green')
N_in_g = Button(text='Н→г', compound="c", image=pixel, width=35, height=35, command = N_in_g, relief=FLAT, bg='green')
g_in_N = Button(text='г→Н', compound="c", image=pixel, width=35, height=35, command = g_in_N, relief=FLAT, bg='green')
lb_in_g = Button(text='фунти→г', compound="c", image=pixel, width=35, height=35, command = lb_in_g, relief=FLAT, bg='green')
g_in_lb = Button(text='г→фунти', compound="c", image=pixel, width=35, height=35, command = g_in_lb, relief=FLAT, bg='green')

'''трикутник'''
trik_text=Label(text="Трикутник", anchor=S, height=3, bg='white')
cos=Button(text='cos', compound='c', image=pixel, width=35, height=35, relief=FLAT, bg='red')
sin=Button(text='sin', compound='c', image=pixel, width=35, height=35, relief=FLAT, bg='red')

"""Інше"""
other_text=Label(text="Інше", anchor=N, height=2, bg='white')
v1 = Button(text='км/год\nв\nм/с', compound="c", image=pixel, width=35, height=35, relief=FLAT, bg='pink', command=v1)
v2 = Button(text='м/с\nв\nкм/год', compound="c", image=pixel, width=35, height=35, relief=FLAT, bg='pink', command=v2)
x_2 = Button(text='²√x', compound='c', image=pixel, width=35, height=35, relief=FLAT, bg='pink', command=x_2)
x_y = Button(text='xʸ', compound='c', image=pixel, width=35, height=35, relief=FLAT, bg='pink', command=x_y)
rad_in_gradus = Button(text='рад→x°', compound='c', image=pixel, width=35, height=35, relief=FLAT, bg='pink')
gradus_in_rad = Button(text='x°→рад', compound='c', image=pixel, width=35, height=35, relief=FLAT, bg='pink')


'''С помощью функции grid() упаковуем все виджети '''

'''Температура'''
#l_t.grid(row=1, column=4, columnspan=4)
c_in_f.grid(row=1, column=4, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, ipady=0)
f_in_c.grid(row=1, column=6, columnspan=2, rowspan=2,ipady=0)

'''Масса'''
#l_m.grid(row=2, column=4,rowspan=2, columnspan=4)
kar_in_g.grid(row=3, column=4, columnspan=2, padx=1)
g_in_kar.grid(row=3, column=6, columnspan=2, padx=1)
N_in_g.grid(row=4, column=4, columnspan=2, padx=1)
g_in_N.grid(row=4, column=6, columnspan=2, padx=1)
lb_in_g.grid(row=5, column=4, columnspan=2, padx=1)
g_in_lb.grid(row=5, column=6, columnspan=2, padx=1)

'''Трикутник'''
#trik_text.grid(row=4, column=8, columnspan=4)
cos.grid(row=5, column=8, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, padx=1)
sin.grid(row=5, column=10, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, padx=1)

#other_text.grid(row=1, column=8, columnspan=4, pady=10)
v1.grid(row=1, column=8, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, padx=1)
v2.grid(row=1, column=10, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, padx=1)
x_2.grid(row=2, column=10, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, padx=1)
x_y.grid(row=2, column=8, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, padx=1)
rad_in_gradus.grid(row=3, column=8, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, padx=1)
gradus_in_rad.grid(row=3, column=10, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, padx=1)

b_clean.grid(row=1, column=2)
b_clean1.grid(row=1, column=3)
b_plus.grid(row=1, column=0)
b_minus.grid(row=1, column=1)
b_division.grid(row=2, column=3, rowspan=2, ipady=1)
b_multiply.grid(row=4, column=3, rowspan=2, ipady=1)
b_is.grid(row=5, column=2)
b_float.grid(row=5, column=1)
b1.grid(row=2, column=0)
b2.grid(row=2, column=1)
b3.grid(row=2, column=2)
b4.grid(row=3, column=0)
b5.grid(row=3, column=1)
b6.grid(row=3, column=2)
b7.grid(row=4, column=0)
b8.grid(row=4, column=1)
b9.grid(row=4, column=2)
b0.grid(row=5, column=0)
e.grid(ipady=15, ipadx=110, row=0, column=0, columnspan=12)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне вставить текст над кнопками?
1.Температура
2. Масса
3. Інше
4. Трикутник

Пожалуйста объясните как оно работает.

Comment: https://python-scripts.com/tkinter-layout-example

Comment: Делайте три фрейма: в первом цифровые кнопки, во втором - голубые и темнозеленые, в третьем - розовые и красные. Внутри каждого фрейма по сетке размещаете все что вам нужно.

Comment: можете показать как?

Comment: Могу. Вот мой ответ к одному из предыдущих ваших вопросов: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1144473/1365

Comment: Я только что попытался так сделать, не получилось((

Comment: @СтаніславНетреба, что конкретно не получилось?

Comment: как фото отправить?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBUYe.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не буду переделывать вашу программу, просто покажу как в целом такой интерфейс реализовывается. Сначала просто набросок интерфейса - будет текстовое поле, под ним три фрейма, в каждом по одной метке:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

entry = Entry(root)
entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.grid(row=1, column=0)

Label(frame1, text="Frame 1").grid(row=0, column=0)

frame2 = Frame(root)
frame2.grid(row=1, column=1)

Label(frame2, text="Frame 2").grid(row=0, column=0)

frame3 = Frame(root)
frame3.grid(row=1, column=2)

Label(frame3, text="Frame 3").grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Скриншот]

Обратите внимание, что для меток первым параметром я указываю родительский фрейм. Если родительский фрейм не указать, то метки прикрепятся в само окно, причем все в левую верхнюю ячейку, получится такая ерунда:

[image: Кривой интерфейс]

Если же родительский фрейм указывать, они прикрепляются в левую верхнюю ячейку в сетке своего фрейме (нумерация ячеек сетки внутри каждого фрейма независимая). Точно так же нужно указывать родительский фрейм и для других виджетов, чтобы они крепились в этот фрейм, а не в само окно.

Добавляем кнопочек в фреймы, для удобства заполнение каждого фрейма делаем в отдельных функциях:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

entry = Entry(root)
entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='we')


def init_left_frame(parent):
    frame = Frame(parent)

    Button(frame, text='+').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe')
    Button(frame, text='-').grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nswe')
    Button(frame, text='C').grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='nswe')
    Button(frame, text='->').grid(row=0, column=3, sticky='nswe')

    Button(frame, text='1').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nswe')
    Button(frame, text='2').grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nswe')
    Button(frame, text='3').grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='nswe')

    Button(frame, text='4').grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nswe')
    Button(frame, text='5').grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='nswe')
    Button(frame, text='6').grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='nswe')

    Button(frame, text='7').grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='nswe')
    Button(frame, text='8').grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='nswe')
    Button(frame, text='9').grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='nswe')

    Button(frame, text='0').grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='nswe')
    Button(frame, text='.').grid(row=4, column=1, sticky='nswe')
    Button(frame, text='=').grid(row=4, column=2, sticky='nswe')

    Button(frame, text=':').grid(row=1, column=3, rowspan=2, sticky='nswe')
    Button(frame, text='*').grid(row=3, column=3, rowspan=2, sticky='nswe')

    return frame


def init_central_frame(parent):
    frame = Frame(root)

    Label(frame, text="Температура").grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

    Button(frame, text='C-F').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nswe')
    Button(frame, text='F-C').grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nswe')

    Label(frame, text="Масса").grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

    Button(frame, text='1').grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='nswe')
    Button(frame, text='2').grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='nswe')

    Button(frame, text='3').grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='nswe')
    Button(frame, text='4').grid(row=4, column=1, sticky='nswe')

    Button(frame, text='5').grid(row=5, column=0, sticky='nswe')
    Button(frame, text='6').grid(row=5, column=1, sticky='nswe')

    return frame


def init_right_frame(parent):
    frame = Frame(root)

    Label(frame, text="Разное").grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

    Button(frame, text='1').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nswe')
    Button(frame, text='2').grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nswe')

    Button(frame, text='3').grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nswe')
    Button(frame, text='4').grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='nswe')

    Button(frame, text='5').grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='nswe')
    Button(frame, text='6').grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='nswe')

    Label(frame, text="Треугольник").grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)

    Button(frame, text='7').grid(row=5, column=0, sticky='nswe')
    Button(frame, text='8').grid(row=5, column=1, sticky='nswe')

    return frame


init_left_frame(root).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='n')
init_central_frame(root).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='n')
init_right_frame(root).grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='n')

root.mainloop()
```

Видно что сетки в трех фреймах независимые:

[image: Кнопочки]

Для большей "красоты" еще сделаю, чтобы строки первого фрейма расширились, и он стал такой же высоты как другие два фрейма:

```
...

def init_left_frame(parent):
    frame = Frame(parent)

    ...

    frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    frame.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
    frame.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
    frame.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)

    return frame


...

init_left_frame(root).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ns')
```

Результат:

[image: Красота]